# How to optimize performance of this SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the age for each day, but I need it for all previous dates in one query. So I used the following query:

```
 select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 **DATE**
 ,trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date **AGE**   from items
connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0
```

I am getting output (FOR DATE & AGE) which is fine and correct:

```
 DATE               AGE
   --------- ----------
   6-JUL-15          22
   5-JUL-15          21
   4-JUL-15          20
   3-JUL-15          19
   2-JUL-15          18
   1-JUL-15          17
   30-JUN-15         16
   29-JUN-15         15
   28-JUN-15         14
   27-JUN-15         13
   26-JUN-15         12
   25-JUN-15         11
   24-JUN-15         10
```

Now I need to calculate **average age** for each day so I added average in the following query:

```
  select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 **DATE** ,
    **avg**(trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date )** AVERAGE_AGE**   
    from items
    connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0
    group by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1
```

Is this query correct? When I add aggregate function (avg) to this query, it takes 1 hour to retrieve data. When I remove the average function from query it gives result in 2 seconds? What is the possible solution to calculate average without affecting the performance?

Comment: When you say results in two seconds.... is that scrolling tall the way the end of the dataset? Because returns the start of the results quickly but to find the `AVG` it has to go through all the records regardless.

Comment: What's in the items table?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have never used Oracle, so there might be some mistakes even though I tried to read the doc for syntax details :

You said this query was doing the work in 2 seconds :

```
select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 **DATE**
 ,trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date **AGE**   from items
connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0
```

So we will keep it and make a `view` from it :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
(select 
    trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 **DATE** AS "date_col",
    trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date **AGE** AS "age_col"  
from items
connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0);
```

But probably we could have gained some redundant calculation by doing :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW distinct_dates AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 AS "date_distinct"
from items
connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
(select 
    date_distinct AS "date_col",
    date_distinct - created_date AS "age_col"  
from distinct_dates
connect by date_distinct - created_date > 0);
```

Why did I do that ? Because it seems the problem comes from aggregating and I am afraid the view is in fact calculated multiple times in your code. The next step is just calculating on the view :

```
select 
    date_col ,
    AVG(age_col)
from my_view
group by date_col;
```

In order to conclude, the final code would be :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW distinct_dates AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 AS "date_distinct"
from items
connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
(select 
    date_distinct AS "date_col",
    date_distinct - created_date AS "age_col"  
from distinct_dates
connect by date_distinct - created_date > 0);

select 
    date_col ,
    AVG(age_col)
from my_view
group by date_col;
```

OR if it did not work :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
(select 
    trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 **DATE** AS "date_col",
    trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date **AGE** AS "age_col"  
from items
connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0);


select 
    date_col ,
    AVG(age_col)
from my_view
group by date_col;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified query:

```
select tdate, avg(trunc(tdate)-created_date) AVG_AGE
  from (
    select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 tdate
      from (select min(created_date) dt from items)
      connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - dt > 0 ) dates
  join items on dates.tdate > items.created_date
  group by tdate order by tdate
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3281/3)</sup>

Let's say you have only two rows with dates '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-20'. 
According to my calculations your hierarchical query generates 1376254 rows for them which is probably not what you wanted,
it should generate 51 rows (35+16). This is why it takes so long, for more rows in table `items` output grows exponentially.

You could modify your query by adding some kind of counter (generated by `rownum` or `row_number`)
and then add `and prior rn = rn` to `connect by` clause, but query shown above makes it in simpler way. 
I added that second query in SQLFiddle to compare results, both produced same output.